# Macro para excluir linha de tabela filtrada

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macro

Criei uma tabela com dados de um balanço de contas e estou fazendo uma macro para selecionar apenas alguns valores. Uma atribuição da macro seria filtrar em uma das colunas todos os valores zerados, de modo a excluir as linhas dessas contas que não tiveram movimento.

Depois de realizar o filtro, tento excluir apenas as linhas filtradas da tabela, mas não consigo.

Alguém saberia me informar se há uma maneira de fazê-lo?

Answer (score 1):

Uma opção seria aplicar o algoritmo abaixo. A planilha não precisa estar filtrada para o funcionamento do mesmo.

A Sub *apagaLinhas* recebe uma coluna como parametro e, a partir da linha 2, percorre as celulas que possuem valor = 0 na linha corrente e coluna passada como parametro. Caso o valor seja = 0, então a linha corrente é deletada.

```
Sub apagaLinhas(coluna As Integer)
    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    Dim linha As Long

    Set sheet = Worksheets("Plan1")
    linha = 2

    While (sheet.Cells(linha, coluna).Value <> "")
        If (sheet.Cells(linha, coluna).Value = 0) Then
            sheet.Rows(linha).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Else
            linha = linha + 1
        End If
    Wend
End Sub
```

Utilize a função abaixo para testar.

```
Sub teste()
    apagaLinhas (2)
End Sub
```